# Google Earth Engine ReduceResolution scale

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to optimize my code to run more efficiently on Google Earth Engine (Python API) and want to make sure that I am understanding and using the 'scale' parameter correctly.

I am using the MODIS land cover (MODIS/061/MCD12Q1) and albedo (MODIS/061/MCD43A3) datasets to parse out albedo values for different land cover types and then aggregate it at a larger scale (currently 0.5 degrees, but I may change this).

```
yr = 2010 #currently looking at one year of data at a time
start_date = ee.Date.fromYMD(yr,1,1)
end_date = start_date.advance(1,'year')

albedo_data = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MCD43A3").filterDate(start_date,end_date)
lc_data = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MCD12Q1").filterDate(start_date,end_date)
lc_scale = lc_data.projection().nominalScale() #approx. 500 m

lc = 5 #mixed forest land cover type (can change this value to get results for differnt land cover types)

def albedo_bls_daily(image): #calculates daily bluesky albedo for one land cover type
    albedo_bks_x = image.select('Albedo_BSA_shortwave').multiply(0.001) #get blacksky albedo values
    albedo_ws_x = image.select('Albedo_WSA_shortwave').multiply(0.001) #get whitesky albedo values
    
    #mask out invalid data (i.e. albedo values below 0 or above 1)
    albedo_bks_mask = albedo_bks_x.where(albedo_bks_x.lte(0),0).where(albedo_bks_x.gt(0),1).where(albedo_bks_x.gte(1),0) 
    albedo_bks_x = albedo_bks_x.updateMask(albedo_bks_mask)
    
    albedo_ws_mask = albedo_ws_x.where(albedo_ws_x.lte(0),0).where(albedo_ws_x.gt(0),1).where(albedo_ws_x.gte(1),0)
    albedo_ws_x = albedo_ws_x.updateMask(albedo_ws_mask)
    
    #calculate bluesky albedo 
    albedo_bls_x = (albedo_bks_x.add(albedo_ws_x)).divide(2) 
    
    #land cover mask (mask for albedo data to block out all except the desired land cover type)
    lc_igbp_x = lc_data.first()
    lc_type_mask_x = lc_igbp_x.where(lc_igbp_x.neq(lc),0).where(lc_igbp_x.eq(lc),1) 
    
    albedo_bls_x = albedo_bls_x.updateMask(lc_type_mask_x)
    
    #spatial averaging using reduce neighbourhood
    albedo_bls_x = albedo_bls_x.reduceNeighborhood(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(),
                                                   kernel = ee.Kernel.square(radius = 24,
                                                                             units = 'pixels'),
                                                   skipMasked = False,
                                                   inputWeight = 'mask')
    #set time of image
    albedo_bls_x = albedo_bls_x.set({'system:time_start':image.get('system:time_start')})
    return albedo_bls_x

def albedo_bls_monthly(m): #averages the daily bluesky values into monthly values
    img = albedo_data.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).map(albedo_bls_daily).mean()
    return img

#maps monthly bluesky albedo values over all 12 months
months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12)
albedo_bls_all = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(months.map(albedo_bls_monthly)) 

#convert from img collection to img with 12 bands (one per month)
band_names = ['01_Jan','02_Feb','03_Mar','04_Apr','05_May','06_Jun','07_Jul','08_Aug','09_Sep','10_Oct','11_Nov','12_Dec']
albedo_bls_all = albedo_bls_all.toBands().rename(band_names).reproject('EPSG:4326', scale = lc_scale)  

#reduce regions to averages over a 0.5 x 0.5 degree grid over Canada
albedo_geom_ee = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/kloog-project-1/assets/albedo_geom_base') #0.5 by 0.5 degree grid of cells
canada = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/kloog-project-1/assets/canada_boundary_2021') #simplified outline of Canada

albedo_bls_shp = albedo_bls_all.reduceRegions(collection = albedo_geom_ee.filterBounds(canada),
                                              reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(),
                                              scale = lc_scale, #original scale of land cover data
                                              tileScale=16)

#exoprt to Drive
ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(collection = albedo_bls_shp,
                              description = str('albedo_bls_shp_lc_'+str(lc)+'_'+str(yr)),
                              fileNamePrefix = str('albedo_bls_shp_lc_'+str(lc)+'_'+str(yr)),
                              fileFormat = 'SHP').start()
```

I have done the reduceRegions with the scale set to the original scale of the data (~500 m) here and I am trying to figure out how I could run it at a larger scale without it impacting the results. Because the land cover data is discrete data and I am using it to mask out unwanted albedo values, I can't see how this could work. From the GEE guide "For discrete valued images, pixel values of upper levels of the pyramid are a sample (usually the top left pixel) of pixels at the next lower level". So I believe that this would mean that my land cover data at a larger scale would look something like this:
[image: land cover data at 500 and 3000 m scales]

If I used this larger scale, this would really impact my mask for land cover type. At the 500 m scale for the "(5) Mixed Forest", I would only take albedo values from three of the pixels, whereas at the larger scale, we would take the albedo of the whole area. Am I understanding the scale parameter here correctly? Is there some way to run it at a larger scale without it impacting my results like this, or am I stuck running it at the native scale?